# Antlr parser integration in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, antlr

As part of a professional project, I have need of a small parser for interpreting boolean-type inputs. I was able to use Antlr to create a working parser, and I was wondering if anybody here had experience and/or tips on integrating this parser, with the required Antlr libraries, into my Symfony2 application.

I have a class defining individual conditions (such as "attribute is greater than argument"), and I needed a way to combine these different conditions to create filters on the data within my application. The best way I found was to create another "container" class, referencing these conditions and having the information needed to combine them to produce the filter I need (basically a combination of DQL conditions). My problem stems from the client's request of being able to save and modify these filters, meaning I needed a simple way to keep them in database and recreate the whole filter.
Having these condition objects, I chose to use a Domain-Specific Language that I can use to save queries in the container (I dislike directly saving queries since they're difficult to modify afterwards IMO). I can save my filters in the container class in the form "((NOT condition1 AND condition2) OR (condition1 AND NOT condition2)) AND NOT condition3 OR condition4.

I have generated the associated parser, but now I need to integrate it in my Symfony project, meaning I need to integrate the Antlr library as well, and I don't really know how to proceed. I was thinking I could attempt to format the Antlr library as a Symfony Bundle, but I'm wondering what other ways there could be, and the comparative difficulties.
Does anybody have alternative approaches, as well as associated pros and cons?